# After Windows 10 latest update VB6 hangs

Tags: windows, vb6

Last night Microsoft Decided to Update Windows 10.  I have been running VB6 on Windows 10 since Windows 10 was originally released.  Now when I try to run VB6 the VB6 splash screen is displayed and then I get [a window titled Windows Installer, a message that says Preparing to install, a button that says Cancel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bpJK.jpg) a window titled Windows Installer, a message that says Preparing to install, a button that says Cancel.  This window is modal and does not allow me to get to VB6.  If I click Cancel the process repeats.  If I click on a .vbp the same thing happens. Please help

Thank you
Charlie

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if I should apologize or demand an apology from Microsoft.  I right clicked on VB6 and chose Compatibility Checker.  After it ran, Microsoft decided to update office 2010 Single Image (whatever that is).  Then I clicked on Test the Module and guess what? It worked.  I so hate updates...I had this problem and now my computer reboots every night, thus trashing any open files and ruining my Free Cell game :-)

Hope this helps somebody else who is frustrated.

BTW shouldn't it be Windows' Installer.  Doesn't the Installer belong to Windows?

Happy Computing
Charlie

Comment: FWIW I wound up uninstalling all of my Office 2010 stuff because of a similar problem.  Turns out  I had several older versions of Office on my machine, problems went away after uninstalling everything except the most current.